# PUG wrong encapsulation after condition

Tags: pug, conditional-statements

I can not solve the problem with the encapsulation of blocks after the condition. After compiling the PUG, the block is placed next to the link, not inside this link =(

**Screenshot in Google Chrome**

[image]

**PUG code:**

```pug
-
    var href = 'javascript:void(0);',
        menu = {
            'Овощи, зелень':           href,
            'Фрукты, ягоды':           href,
            'Орехи, сухофрукты':       href,
            'Молочные продукты':       href,
            'Мясо, птица, яйца':       href,
            'Рыба, морепродукты': {
                expanded: false,
                href: href,
                group: {
                    'Охлажденная рыба':                  href,
                    'Соленая и копченая рыба':           href,
                    'Свежемороженная рыба':              href,
                    'Икра':                              href,
                    'Морепродукты':                      href,
                    'Крабовое мясо и палочки':           href,
                    'Морская капуста и закуски из рыбы': href,
                    'Вся рыба и морепродукты':           href
                }
            }
        }
    ;

block justSomeBlock
    - let index = 0;
    if menu && typeof menu === 'object'
        menu#menu.menu(type='context' label='Меню' contextmenu='menu__group')
            each menu__val, menu__key in menu
                #{'menuitem'}(class='menu__item' label='' + menu__key + '')
                    a.menu__link(href='' + (typeof menu__val === 'object' ? menu__val.href : menu__val || '#') + '' class='' + (menu__val.expanded ? 'expanded' : '') + '')
                        .menu__link-text= menu__key

                    if menu__val && typeof menu__val === 'object'
                        menu.menu__group(type='list' id='menu__group--' + ++index +'')
                            if menu__val.group && typeof menu__val.group === 'object'
                                each group__val, group__key in menu__val.group
                                    #{'menuitem'}(class='menu__item' label='' + group__key + '')
                                        a.menu__link(href='' + (typeof group__val === 'object' ? group__val.href : group__val || '#') + '' class='' + (group__val.expanded ? 'expanded' : '') + '')
                                            .menu__link-text= group__key
```

Comment: You just need to move your whole `if` block one indent right, if you want the content inside `if` to come inside the anchor tag.

Comment: I think i already has tried it, but i'll try again and set comment bellow

Comment: Hmm, your comment help. It strange because i tried it before and it doesn't work until my computer was rebooted...

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent your second if-block once more, as suggested in the comments.